# Pythonからエクセルシートの値を参照、編集したい

Tags: python, excel

2つのエクセルファイルがあり、入っている値は以下の通り。

1) パーツ番号、 Yes/No、 Exemption番号
2) パーツ番号

2)のパーツ番号と、1)のパーツ番号が一致したら、2)のファイルに、 Yes/No,
  Exemption 番号を記入するということをPython で行おうとしています。

作業
1)のファイルから辞書を作り、pyファイルとして保存.
　このファイルの中身と　2)のパーツ番号が一致するものがあったら、Yes/No, Exemption番号を2)の
指定セルに記入する。

そもそもこのようなことが可能なのか？

Answer (score 3):

> そもそもこのようなことが可能なのか？

可能だと思います。

[openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) など、Excel操作用のパッケージがあるので、それらを利用すればできると思います。(参考: [Python openpyxlでExcelを操作](https://qiita.com/tftf/items/07e4332293c2c59799d1))